# GraphView Axis Labels

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm using GraphView to draw graphs in my android app, but I'm not able to set axis labels on the X and Y axis which denote what they represent. I checked the documentation, but couldn't find anything useful. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're right. there is no build in method to do it. You have to place your label views yourself at the left resp. bottom of the graphview. This can be done for example with RelativeLayout.

Comment: That's what I thought. Think I'll just move to another library instead.

Comment: in the meanwhile i implemented this feature in GraphView 4.0. Vertical Axis Title, Horizontal Axis Title and Graph Title can be defined with specific color and font size

Comment: @jjoe64 I am having trouble getting these axis labels (or the title) to display. I am fetching the getGridLabelRenderer() for the graph and calling setVerticalAxisTitle() and others, but its not showing up. I am using version 4 of the library, and using the jar in Eclipse.

Comment: @mstenroos can you create an issue at the github issue tracker and provide source code of your app and the device/android version you are using, so i can test it